# css - how to hide href link nested inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an anchor tag inside it. I want to set the display of just the "a" tag as none. How would I go about doing it? It looks like-

```
<div id="upper">
    <a href="http://myLink">Hide Me!</a>
    <p>Not to hide this text </p>
</div>
```

I tried doing -

```
#upper a {display:none;}
```

However this does not work for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That works: http://jsfiddle.net/wsaKr/ You muse be doing something else wrong then. Show us more of your code.

Comment: Are you reusing `#upper` in other elements?

Comment: do you have a script running on the page thats changing the default style of the link?  Or is the css rule directly before it closed properly?  Check it in firebug or chrome console.

Comment: Per the comments of others, there's nothing wrong with your code. You could also provide greater specificity via #upper a:first-child {display:none}​

Comment: Try to give your `<a>` an id, and use `#upper #upper_a_id {}` in your CSS. Or look for any `!important;` for `<a>` in your CSS, that could override your rule.

Comment: As others have stated, your code is working.  Show us something that demonstrates your problem case.

Comment: I recomend you to use Firebug to see what propertis the `<a>` tag has. Probably you are overwriting some property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone suggests, don't `#upper a {display:none !important;}` as this introduce more issues in the future than it would sove immediately.

`#upper a {display:none;}` would work unless there is a more specific rule overriding it somewhere, this can be inspected with firebug or Chrome inspector etc.